# How can I sequence a bunch of queries in a loop?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a series of MySQL queries that I want to run, which I have kept in an array. But when I used a loop to execute these commands, the commands only run after the entire loop is over.

```
var i = 0;
    while(i<tableCommands.length) 
     {

        connection.query(tableCommands[i],function(err,result)
        {
            if (err) 
                {
                    throw err;
                    process.exit(1);
                }
            console.log("table no "+i+" has been created");
            i++;
        })

     }
```

I expected the output to be "table no 1 has been created" and so on, but I'm stuck in a while loop that gives no output

Comment: i assume you are using `Node.js` ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes I am

Comment: You're incrementing `i` inside the callback function, if that is run async (which I bet it is), you will end up with a lot more iterations then `tableCommands.length`

Comment: @Titus the thing is if I logged something right before the line "connection.query....." , that is logged infinitely. So the loop not only runs for some more iterations, I'm essentially stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion instead:

```
function query (index) {
  connection.query(tableCommands[index] function () {
     ...
     if (++index < tableCommands.length) {
        query(index);
     }
  });
}
```

This will run the queries one at the time, if you want to run them all in parallel, you can do something like this:

```
function query (index) {
  connection.query(tableCommands[index] function () {
     ...
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < tableCommands.length; i++) {
  query(i);
}
```

This will increment `i` after each iteration not after the response to the query comes in. It also creates a closure so `i` won't end up with a different value then the one used for the query (`let` will prevent that as well).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a solid idea of how to solve the current problem and an insight as to how to approach future problems.